# Не отлаживаает программу в QT

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Когда пытаюсь отладить программу возникает следующая проблема,что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Инструкция по настройке отладчика [тут](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html).

Comment: Что-то не получается

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Хорошо,я это учту.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по логам, Вы запускаете release версию, смените профиль на debug.

Comment: Да,нужно было переключиться,и установить debugger,которого у меня не было.